# Each image less than the previous

Tags: javascript, image, image-scaling

I have array with 5 images, which I displayed with PHP. How can I use JavaScript to diplay them such that each image is 10% lower than the previous?

```
foreach($top_images as $top_i) {
    echo '#'.$ratio;
    echo '
        <br><img src="'.$top_i['url'].'" ><br>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                var img = new Image();
                img.src = "'.$top_i['url'].'";
                img.onload = function() {
                    var width = this.width;
                    var height = this.height;
                    ratio = '.json_encode($ratio).';
                    this.width = this.width - this.width * ratio/10;
                    this.height = this.height - this.height * ratio/10;
                }
                });
        </script>
    ';
    $ratio++;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't mix up php and js like you did. Just output the images normally with php and then add the js at the bottom of your site: http://jsfiddle.net/78hdpkzr/

```
$(document).load(function() {
    lastHeight = 0;
    $("img").each(function(i) {
        if (i != 0) {
            $(this).css({
                height: lastHeight / 100 * 90
            })
        }
        lastHeight = parseInt($(this).css('height'));
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS and the next selector (works on all browsers)

Only thing is the images have to be next to each other

CSS:

```css
img {
  width: 100px;
  float:left;
  clear:both;
}
img + img {
  width: 90px;
}
img + img + img {
  width: 80px;
}
img + img + img + img {
  width: 70px;
}
img + img + img + img + img {
  width: 60px;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
<img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
<img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
<img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
<img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
```